# Is it a good idea to store two hashes for each password in a database?

Tags: hash, cryptography, passwords

Is it a good idea to store two hashes for each password in a database (e.g. SHA-1 and MD5) and check both of the hashes in a login script to prevent collisions? On the other side, wouldn't it then be easier to calculate the password from the two hashes (for example if a hacker gets access to the database)?

Comment: [See this answer at crypto stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31165). Summary, the odds are around 2^64 of a collision and assuming you have two hashes that are the same, they're separate accounts so how would any one know?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on crypto.se.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably not be useful.

Any hash function you'd use will be safe against accidental collisions -- they're almost impossibly unlikely. So the only collisions you're concerned with are when hackers have already compromised your database, and have your hashes, trying to figure out a password that generates the target hash.

This is called a "second preimage attack", and it's incredibly hard. There are no known second preimage attacks for any relatively recent algorithm, even going back to MD4. This shouldn't be a serious concern.

However, if you're using a generic hash function, then people brute-forcing your hacked hashes *is* a realistic concern. **You shouldn't use a generic hash function like SHA-2, even with salts**. You should use a password hash function, like bcrypt, which is resistant to brute-forcing. If you are using normal hash functions then, as you note, storing two means they only need to brute force the weaker one -- it's one more thing that can go wrong.

Don't bother. Use a password hash function instead. It will be safer and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see how there can be any benefit from storing 2 hashes for the password and then checking both.  All you're doing here is giving your app more work to do and in my opinion not providing any extra level of security as they are still entering the same password.

Comment: It would prevent this sort of attack, [Shattered SHA1](https://shattered.io/), as the md5 would still fail to match.